# Coordinate out of bounds

Tags: java, file

I am doing an exercise which consists of saving the rgb of each pixel of an image in a text file but it tells me:

Coordinate out of bounds! BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

It only generates the file but does not write anything to someone to help me, here is the code:

````
package Proyecto;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class pixel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File originalImage = new File("imagen.jpg");
        
        BufferedImage img = null;
        
        try{
            img = ImageIO.read(originalImage);
            File arch = new File("Pixel.txt");
            BufferedWriter archOut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(arch));
            int w = img.getWidth();
            int h = img.getHeight();
            for(int i=0; i<w; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<h; j++){
                    Color c = new Color(img.getRGB(j, i));
                    int r = c.getRed();
                    int g = c.getGreen();
                    int b = c.getBlue();
                    int a = c.getAlpha();
                    archOut.write(r+","+g+","+b+","+a+"\t");
                }
                archOut.newLine();
            }
        }catch(FileNotFoundException FNFe){
            System.out.println("No fue posible la lectura del archivo con scanner");
            System.out.println(FNFe.getMessage());
        }catch(IOException IOe){
            System.out.println("Error en lectira/escitura");
            System.out.println(IOe.getMessage());
        }catch(NumberFormatException NFe){
            System.out.println("Error en la conversion de tipos");
            System.out.println(NFe.getMessage());
        }catch(NullPointerException NPe){
            System.out.println("Error en arreglo de cadenas");
            System.out.println(NPe.getMessage());
        }catch(Exception EX){
            System.out.println(EX.getMessage());
        }
    }
} ```
````

Comment: @AlexRudenko Please don't translate posts. Redirect them to a SO website of their language, or leave a close flag. https://pt.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Andreas ok, I'll keep that in mind

Comment: @AlexRudenko :) https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684 (two last paragraphs)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, pixel coordinates are misplaced when getting the pixel color, according to the [JavaDoc for `BufferedImage::getRGB`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB(int,%20int))

It should be:

```
Color c = new Color(img.getRGB(i, j)); // i - x, j - y
```